# How can I fill a column based on a difference between the values of two different columns, using groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

| HorseId | FGrating | Max FGrating | Top |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1736 | 110 |  | No (no Max FGrating to compare with) |
| 1736 | 124 | 110 | Yes (FGrating - Max FGrating>=4) |
| 1736 | 118 | 124 | No (FGrating - Max FGrating <4) |
| 13973 | 144 |  | No (no Max FGrating to compare with) |
| 13973 | 137 | 144 | No (FGrating - Max FGrating <4) |

The `Top` column is "Yes" or "1" when the difference between `FGrating` and `MaxFGrating` for that row is 4 or more.

I know I should use `groupby`, because I need this for each `HorseId` and perhaps the `diff` function, but I cannot put them together.

How can I do it?

Comment: This is actually quite confusing. What is the mathematical equation that causes `Top` to be `No` for the first row? Is it `110 - (-1)`? Or `(-1) - 110`?

Comment: The (-1) means "does not apply" and it is not taken into account. Treat it as a NaN. The formula is FGrating-Max FGrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output is hard to make sense of, because the values in Top do not seem driven by any conditions in the table, except those two rows with `MaxFGrating == -1` seem to be consistently  `MaxFGrating - FGrating`.

```
>>> ((df['FGrating'] - df['Max FGrating']) >= 4).map({True:'Yes', False:'No'})
0    Yes
1    Yes
2     No
3    Yes
4     No
dtype: object
```

Or `MaxFGrating - FGrating`.

```
>>> ((df['Max FGrating'] - df['FGrating']) >= 4).map({True:'Yes', False:'No'})
0     No
1     No
2    Yes
3     No
4    Yes
dtype: object
```

Comment: I had edited and corrected the question